# Bash populate empty array element from previous element

Tags: arrays, bash, join, null

Is there a simple (i.e. non looping) way to take an array in bash and populate any null elements with whatever the previous element value was.

Use case is to take a set of asynchronous time series data points and outer join them with time as the common column. Then for each data column, find any null value and fill in the point with the value of the previous data point in that series.

Thus two series

```
T1,1.234  
T2,2.345  
T3,3.456  
T6,6.789  

T1,1.111  
T2,2.222  
T5,5.555  
T7,7.777
```

Would join to produce

```
T1,1.234,1.111  
T2,2.345,2.222  
T3,3.456,2.222  
T5,3.456,5.555  
T6,6.789,5.555  
T7,6.789,7.777
```

Comment: What do you mean by an array? An associative array where Ti is the key, or just an array of strings with commas inside? Or input files?

Comment: What do you have against loops?

Comment: @choroba - Yes, Ti (typically time) is the key.

Comment: @cdarke - Performance primarily. These are reasonable sized files.

Comment: The join I can do now, and have made some limited progress on the zero element population part...The following `code` gets the previous line's contents (for column 2, which I'm just using as an example), but crucially it only does this on a line by line basis, and therefore doesn't reference the output line by line....


  
cat inputfile.csv | awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } { x[NR] = $2 } END { for ( i=1 ; i<=NR ; i++ ) { if (x[i] >0 ) print x[i]; else print x[i-1] }} ' > outputfile.csv

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't reference the output line by line_?

Comment: @Armali - This means that for example an input sequence of 1.0,n/a,n/a,3.2,4.5,n/a,n/a,n/a,9.0 would yield an output sequence of 1.0,1.0,n/a,3.2,4.5,4.5,n/a,n/a,9.0 

i.e. only the FIRST null value after a non-null gets updated. What I am really after is the unix equivalent of R's na.locf functionality, hopefully in vectorised form for speed. Use case is for an input file of, say, 500k rows * 20 columns. So loops can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `for` loop body in your comment above to

```
{ if (!x[i]) x[i] = x[i-1]; print x[i] }
```

, it works also with consecutive null values.

If an AWK script is too slow for your use case, and since you mentioned R, why not use R?